# return value of anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I want to build a shim. I have the following shim, which excecutes only once and should give the returned value to other functions. It is a bit like that http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/.

```
// WAY 1
matches: function(){
        return Element.prototype.matchesSelector 
        || Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector 
        || Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector 
        || Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector 
        || Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector 
        || Element.prototype.matches 
        || Element.prototype.webkitMatches
        || Element.prototype.mozMatches
        || Element.prototype.msMatches
        || Element.prototype.oMatches;
    }(),
```

Now I want to use the return value by other functions:

```
// Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation (anonymous function)
if(matches('ul')){
...
}
```

However I cannot retrieve the return value of matches, because it s a anonymous function.

It will only work, if I do not excecute the function at once:

```
// WAY 2
matches: function(){
    return Element.prototype.matchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.matches 
    || Element.prototype.webkitMatches
    || Element.prototype.mozMatches
    || Element.prototype.msMatches
    || Element.prototype.oMatches;
},

// Now it works, but the method is executed every time.
if(matches('ul')){
...
}
```

How can I make "WAY 1" work?

Comment: There's something unclear, especially regarding your `if(matches('ul')){` : how do you deal with calling the function with the proper context ?

Comment: I wrapped "matched"-function within an object DomUtil{ matches: function());...}. The call to if(DomUtil.matches('ul')) it executed within a click-handler after dom is loaded. However, it only works, if I use WAY 2 instead of WAY 1. However WAY 2, excecutes the function every time it is called, which is useless, because the returned value does not differ after execution. Hence, I want to make "WAY 1" to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have mentioned, you have a global object named `DOM`, using it you can do it like:

```
matches: (DOM._getMatches = function(){
    return Element.prototype.matchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.matches 
    || Element.prototype.webkitMatches
    || Element.prototype.mozMatches
    || Element.prototype.msMatches
    || Element.prototype.oMatches;
})(),
```

then call `_getMatches` whenever you want:

```
DOM._getMatches()
```

If you have any other global object in your code, you can use it instead of `DOM`.

Comment: The problem is that the method doesn't work as a method of `window`.

Comment: The above solution works, however, it has some drawbacks. I have something like this: var DOM = {};DOM.util = function(){}; DOM.util.prototype = { matchesNode: ...}. You see I have the matchesNode function within the prototype of my Dom.util. Using something like this does not work: matches: (Dom.util.prototype._getMatches = function(){..}... I dont want to use another object (window) only to store the returned value of matches. matches should stay in Dom.util.

Comment: This works: matches: "matches = (DOM._getMatches = function(){.." This does not work: "matches = (DOM.util._getMatches = function(){..", This does also not work "matches = (DOM.util.prototype._getMatches = function(){.." Why does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

You make it too complex. Just do this :

```
matches: Element.prototype.matchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector 
    || Element.prototype.matches 
    || Element.prototype.webkitMatches
    || Element.prototype.mozMatches
    || Element.prototype.msMatches
    || Element.prototype.oMatches;
```

Comment: That does simplify the original code, but it doesn't actually solve the problem. The same value gets applied to `matches` so when it is called you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function is a function that returns another function.

In the first case, you call it and store the returned function on `matches`. Then you call that returned function later.

The problem is that the purpose of that function is to compare the HTML Element stored in `this` with a selector you pass as an argument.

When you call `matches('ul')` the value of `this` is `window` (or `undefined` in strict mode). That isn't an HTML Element.

You need something more like:

```
matches.apply(document.getElementById('something_that_might_be_a_list', 'ul');
```

Comment: The architecture of the shim-layer in http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ is the same as mine. What differs is, that I do not store the matches() to window or document-object. But I guess, this is not the reason for not to work.

Comment: @nimo23 — As I explained in this answer, storing `matches` on a different kind of object is precisely why it doesn't work.

Comment: The solution of Mehran does indeed work, but only if that object is created before the matches-function is called. This works: var test = {}; matches: (test._getMatches = function(){.. .However, I want to store that method within the prototypes function: DOM.util.prototype._getMatches = function(){.." This, unfortunately, does not work.